# Is it possible to make a composite key with discriminator from inheritance?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have an error with this code :

```
abstract class Foo implements Serializable {
   int weighting

   static mapping = {
     discriminator column: "type"
     id composite: ['weighting',  'type']
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    discriminator value: "bar"
}

class Hello extends Foo {
    discriminator value: "hello"
}
```

Gorm doesn't recognize 'type' and when I add explicitly 'type', I have an "Repeated column in mapping for entity" error.
If I set insertable and updateable to false there is no effects.